# AWS SQS request count dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Where can I find AWS SQS request count dashboard?

There isn't any dashboard like this.

AWS told me that my free tier 1M request in SQS was used during one night, its sh*t.

Need to see some charts of usage.

Comment: [Accessing CloudWatch metrics for Amazon SQS - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-access-metrics.html)

Comment: Where is any request count information?

Comment: You could used `NumberOfMessagesReceived` and `NumberOfEmptyReceives`. Let us know whether you see any metrics there. See: [Available CloudWatch metrics for Amazon SQS - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-available-cloudwatch-metrics.html)